# Как можно узнать был ли несанкционированный доступ или нет

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, взлом

Сегодня каким то странным образом перестал работать shhd. 
После проверки файла обнаружил что он перезаписан и это точно, так как я помню что да как там было. Хотелось бы узнать как можно отследить взлом систем?
Система Centoc 6

Comment: А что именно было изменено? Может пакет обновился и вы, во время обновления, согласились с перезаписью конфигурационного файла?

Comment: Кстати, сама формулировка: "как можно отследить взлом систем?" - это вопрос, сравнимый с: "как можно программировать?".

Comment: Никак не отследить, потому что злоумышленник может прибрать все следы за собой. Вот если он забыл что-то прибрать, тогда можно. Но забыл ли?

Comment: Я ничего не обновлял так как в это время просто верстал и в это время внезапно перестал работать ssh. при попытки запуска говорит /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 75: Bad configuration option: UsePAM . Хотя как если я ничего не трогал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общий смысл - искать то, чего быть не должно, либо искать то, что исчезло, либо то, что изменилось.

- смотреть лишние процессы.
- включить аудит файловой системы.
- проверить файлы, созданные в последнее время.
- проверить лишние модули ядра.
- проверить лишних пользователей.
- проверить лишние способы авторизации.
- проверить наличие популярных руткитов.
- проверить лишние соединения.
- проверить лишние демоны.
- проверить логи авторизации.
- ...

Comment: Всё перечисленное злоумышленник при желании может скрыть.

Comment: В идеальном мире, все можно скрыть, все можно защитить. А в реальном все прозаичнее. Более того, сомневаюсь, что его целенаправленно ломала профессиональная группа хакеров, да еще окапывалась. В лучшем (худшем) случае - это робот эксплуатирующий старые уязвимости и "катастрофически плохие" настройки.

Comment: @andreymal И, да, "злоумышленник" позаботился обо всех вышеперечисленных вариантах обнаружения, но не позаботился сделать конфиг для `sshd` рабочим, как минимум?